# If $\phi$ is a epimorphism from $L_{1}\to L_{2}$, then is it true that $\phi(Z(L_{1}))=Z(L_{2})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

The following is a exercise from the book Introduction to Lie Algebras- Erdmann

Let $\phi:L_{1}\to L_{2}$ be a lie-algebra epimorphism. Are the following true or false:
$\phi(Z(L_{1}))=Z(L_{2})$.

What I think is this is  false. I have shown that $\phi(Z(L_{1}))\subset Z(L_{2})$.  But cannot find a example where this inclusion is proper.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_1 = \Bbb C^2$ with basis $e_1,e_2$ and bracket $[e_1,e_2] = e_1$. Then $\phi : L_1 \to \Bbb C$ defined as $\phi(e_1) = 0, \phi(e_2 ) = 1$ defines a morphism of Lie algebras, with $\phi(Z(L_1)) = 0$. On the other hand, since $L_2$ is abelian $Z(L_2) = L_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra, let $\mathfrak z$ be its center and let $\pi\colon\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{g/z}$ be the natural projection. Then $\pi$ is a Lie algebra epimorphism and, of course, $\pi(\mathfrak{z})=\{0\}$. So, if the center of $\mathfrak{g/z}$ is non-trivial, you're done.

Now, the question is: are there exemples of Lie algebras $\mathfrak g$ such that the center of $\mathfrak{g/z}$ is not trivial? Yes, there are. Take the Heisenberg Lie algebra:$$\mathfrak{g}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&a&c\\0&0&b\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b,c\in\mathbb C\right\}.$$Then$$\mathfrak{z}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&0&c\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b,c\in\mathbb C\right\}$$and $\mathfrak{g/z}$ is the abelian $2$-dimensional Lie algebra.

Comment: Nice example ! (+1)